# IMAP in Php: Marking a message unread/unseen

Tags: php, imap, message

I want to create a script in php to read al mail from a mail acount. I connect to the server, I can see the mails but went I want to seet it back to unseen I can't find a function to do this.

Comment: Please give more information. What exactly is your question? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand this page correctly:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-body.php

You can use the FT_PEEK option to leave the message as 'unread'.

**EDIT AFTER YOUR COMMENTS**

Have you looked at this method?:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-clearflag-full.php

You are able to clear the \\Seen flag.

Comment: I know this. But if see the body and than I return to index.php how can I set it back to unseen ?

Comment: I'm sorry - I don't understand exactly what it is you're trying to do. Can you give a step by step explanation?

Comment: In any mail client (Yahoo Mail, GMail ...) you have this options: "Mark as unread", "Mark as read". How can be done something like this in php?