# Mark mail as unread

Tags: php, email, imap

How do I mark a email as unread? I know I can open the stream as read only, but on some occasions I need to manipulate the message (mark as seen, move to a different folder, etc.), so I need the stream to be read/write. I also know about the "Seen" flag and how to remove it.

So is there a way to mark an email as unread after it has been marked as read?

Here is the code which is removing the 'Seen' flag from the mail:

```
imap_clearflag_full($this->mbox, $mId, '\\Seen', ST_UID);
```

Comment: If you're using the `imap_`* functions, I think you want `imap_clearflag_full()` http://php.net/imap_clearflag_full and unset the `\Seen` flag. I've only played with PHP's mail functions though, not confident enough in that answer.

Comment: That does remove the Seen flag but doesn't affect read/unread, unfortunately. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604016/imap-in-php-marking-a-message-unread-unseen helpful?

Comment: Nope. As I said I'm aware of the ability to open a stream which is read only but that's not the functionality I need atm.

Comment: Is there any chance you can post a snippit of code where you are removing the SEEN flag and it is still appearing as read?

Answer (score 2):

This works for Gmail, verified:

```
imap_clearflag_full($mbox, $i, "\\Seen \\Recent");
imap_expunge($mbox);
```

Comment: This worked for me. Tried using "//Seen" and '//Seen' which don't work. Now "\\Seen" which works! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
imap_clearflag_full($imap_connection, $message, "//Seen");
```

Don't forgot to close the connection.

Not tested here, but may work..

Comment: Tried that. In fact, I have that exact function in my question. Unless you're suggesting that "//Seen" will offer a different result than '\\Seen'.

Comment: Yes, "//Seen" are expected to reset the "\\Seen" flag. Have you tried with the exact code I have posted?

Answer (score 0):

Try code below:

```
imap_clearflag_full($inbox_connection, $email_number, "\\Seen");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
imap_setflag_full($connection, $MailUid, '\\Seen', ST_UID);
```