# Marking an email unread in PHP IMAP

Tags: php, imap

Are there any [PHP IMAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php) functions which can be used to mark an email as unread? I am checking the mail using some IMAP functions that return the messages as read, but I want to make them unread.

Comment: Try this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604016/imap-in-php-marking-a-message-unread-unseen

Answer (score 8):

To mark an email message as unread, you should unset the `\\Seen` flag on that message.
You could use the [`imap_clearflag_full`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-clearflag-full.php) function to clear message flags.

```
// Unset desired flag
imap_clearflag_full($imap_connection, $message_number, "\\Seen");
// Confirm changes
imap_close($imap_connection, CL_EXPUNGE);
```

**Note:**

> "I am checking the mail using some IMAP functions that return the messages as read"

You can set the `FT_PEEK` flag when reading messages, this will not set the `\\Seen` flag if not already set.

```
// This will not mark a message as seen
$body = imap_body($imap_stream, $msg_number, FT_PEEK);
```

Comment: This answer still holds true however the FT_PEEK flag is invalid.  I had to use "\\Seen" and not "//Seen".  No errors displayed so took a bit of time to catch this.

Answer (score 4):

try the [imap_clearflag_full](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imap-clearflag-full.php) ,

```
imap_clearflag_full($mailbox, $email_number, "\\Seen");
```

Answer (score 1):

try the imap_setflag_full, 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-setflag-full.php