# PHP IMAP. Stop Messages Being Marked as Seen

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm retrieving Gmail e-mails through IMAP. I'm setting the FT_PEEK option wherever I can, and finally, I've even opened the mailbox as read-only (OP_READONLY). Yet, my code is marking the messages as read.

Here is the code:

```
class imap{
   CONST HOSTNAME='{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
   CONST USERNAME = '[Address hidden]';
   CONST PASSWORD = '[Password hidden]'; //App password from Google

   function getMessagesSince($date){
      //This will return a collection of email objects.

      $messages=array();
      if(!$imap=imap_open($this::HOSTNAME, $this::USERNAME, $this::PASSWORD, OP_READONLY)) throw new exception("Unable to connect to IMAP mailbox. ".imap_last_error());

      $since=date_format($date, 'j F Y');

      $emails=imap_search($imap, 'SINCE "'.$since.'"', SE_UID|FT_PEEK);

      foreach($emails as $email){
         $messages[]=$this->getMessage($email, $imap);
      }

      imap_close($imap);

      return $messages;
   }

   private function getMessage($uid, $imap){
      //First get the headers
      $headers=$this->getHeaders($uid, $imap);
      $datereceived=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($headers->date));
      $sender=$headers->from[0]->mailbox."@".$headers->from[0]->host;
      $cc=$headers->cc;
      $subject=$headers->subject;

      //Now get the message body
      $message=$this->getBody($uid, $imap);

      $email=new email();
      $email->uid=$uid;
      $email->datereceived=$datereceived;
      $email->sender=$sender;
      $email->cc=$cc;
      $email->subject=$subject;
      $email->message=$message;
      return $email;
   }

   private function getHeaders($uid, $imap){
      //Return an array of headers for the referenced message
      //$overview = imap_fetch_overview($imap, $uid, FT_UID); //As we used the SE_UID flag when searching, we have to use it when fetching.
      //We use this, rather than fetch_overview, because the overview doesn't have the cc information.
      $hText = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, '0', FT_UID|FT_PEEK);
      $headers = imap_rfc822_parse_headers($hText);
      return $headers;
   }
   private function getBody($uid, $imap){
      $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/HTML");
      // if HTML body is empty, try getting text body
      if ($body == "") {
         $body = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, "TEXT/PLAIN");
      }
      return $body;
   }

   private function get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $structure = false, $partNumber = false){
      if (!$structure) {
         $structure = imap_fetchstructure($imap, $uid, FT_UID);
      }
      if ($structure) {
         if ($mimetype == $this->get_mime_type($structure)) {
               if (!$partNumber) {
                  $partNumber = 1;
               }
               $text = imap_fetchbody($imap, $uid, $partNumber, FT_UID|FT_PEEK);
               switch ($structure->encoding) {
                  case 3:
                     return imap_base64($text);
                  case 4:
                     return imap_qprint($text);
                  default:
                     return $text;
               }
         }

         // multipart
         if ($structure->type == 1) {
               foreach ($structure->parts as $index => $subStruct) {
                  $prefix = "";
                  if ($partNumber) {
                     $prefix = $partNumber . ".";
                  }
                  $data = $this->get_part($imap, $uid, $mimetype, $subStruct, $prefix . ($index + 1));
                  if ($data) {
                     return $data;
                  }
               }
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   private function get_mime_type($structure){
      $primaryMimetype = ["TEXT", "MULTIPART", "MESSAGE", "APPLICATION", "AUDIO", "IMAGE", "VIDEO", "OTHER"];

      if ($structure->subtype) {
         return $primaryMimetype[(int)$structure->type] . "/" . $structure->subtype;
      }
      return "TEXT/PLAIN";
   }
}
```

Can anyone spot something I'm missing?

(This is just some extra text, because it's saying that the post is mostly code. I'm just typing here until it lets me post.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12811520/marking-an-email-unread-in-php-imap

Comment: This actually looks okay (except search can't take FT_PEEK).  Are you absolutely sure this is the only thing accessing the mailbox?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the delay. The only thing accessing the mailbox are my mail clients on other devices (iOS, Mac). These aren't marking them as read until I actually read them. Somehow, this code is. If I disable the CRON job that runs this script, they stop being marked.

Answer (score -1):

You should delete OP_READONLY flag from `imap_open()` .